# Should there be a bundling mechanism for duplicate questions?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

Here is my definition by saying "bundling mechanism":

To be able to create a bundle of question-answers for repetitive asked question to preserve the value of the most recently answered duplicate question.

It is happening more and more often that the newly joined users would not find their answer (because their issue is slightly different to already answered questions), hence they create a new question.

Currently the response to such scenario is either of the two:

- Someone comes across and flags it as duplicate question.
- Users start answering the slightly different question and some time later someone comes and raises it as duplicate.

The bundling mechanism would let the users decide if the answers are valued they could vote to bundle it with suggested duplicates. If question is exactly same as asked or answers are exactly same as already given then it is flagged as duplicate.

To list the benefits of bundling mechanism:

1. If question is slightly different: it would mean better coverage of the issue/topic.
2. The answers maybe more up-to-date or descriptive than the answers to the duplicate questions.
3. There will be less discussion on whether question is duplicate or not and more helpful answers covering a bigger range.
4. Better chance for the questioner to get her/his answer.

Comment: Merging is already possible today, but it's a manual moderator action.

Comment: In general I like the idea of moving answers between duplicates. It would be great if you could add a description of how this moving should happen. Move all answers if closed as duplicate? Who would be able to move answers, just moderators or normal users?

Comment: @Stijn Yes. However, I see it happening more often that good answers to duplicated questions are wasted.

Comment: @BDL In this "Bundling Mechanism" a user would find the question she/he thinks it is duplicate of and suggests it to be bundled. This can be continued to further more bundling as more duplicate questions are asked. But in this case both the duplicate questions and answers would remain rather than getting merged.

Comment: If you see a question that is an *exact duplicate*, and has answers that would benefit from merging (moving over to the "master" question), then you can flag that question for moderator attention and ask that it be merged. However, you need to be careful when doing this, because a different presentation of what is fundamentally the same question will change how the answers to that question were presented, making a direct merge inappropriate (as they'll be confusingly worded when they appear as answers to the "master" question).

Comment: @CodyGray That is right to my point actually in terms of 'merge' does not always work. If the questions is slightly different but very much on the same line as already answered questions, it is most likely to be ran over by 'duplicate requests' that users thinking twice and raising for a merge.

Comment: So...what would your proposal do differently to fix this problem? How would "bundled" Q&As be presented?

Comment: @CodyGray It would keep the questions and their answers rather than merging as I mentioned. This should persist the value of different types of answers and updated answers. The presentation could look similar to how in `Documentation` tab one topic contains different explanation by different users.

Comment: Documentation's topics were roughly equivalent to a question's answers. I still don't understand how you are proposing to present *multiple questions* with distinct answers. Remember that all questions closed as a duplicate are already linked on the linked questions under the "Linked" heading in the right sidebar.

Comment: If you have a concrete idea in mind of what you want this to look like, you may want to head over to your favourite image editor and draw up a mock-up for the rest of us to see what's going on in your head.